# Как вставить элемент из переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

В переменной b хранится клон объекта span и вместо того чтобы вставился элемент Текст вставляется вот это [object Object]

```
$('span').each(function(){
   var b = $(this).clone();
   $('ul').append('<li>' + b + '</li>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вставляете копию объекта, как текст. Что бы обернуть копию в родителя, используйте функцию `wrap`:

```js
$('span').each(function(){
   var b = $(this).clone();
   $('ul').append(b);
   b.wrap('<li></li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Текст 1</span>
<span>Текст 2</span>
<span>Текст 3</span>
<span>Текст 4</span>

<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Не вышло. Но так получилось: $('span').each(function(){
        var b = $(this).clone();
        $('ul').append(b);
        b.wrap('<li></li>');
    });

Comment: @PeGaS, я только хотел исправить :)

Comment: И в итоге все можно свести к одной строке: `$('span').clone().wrap('<li></li>').parent().appendTo('ul');`

Answer (score 2):

Вы всё правильно написали, что в переменной хранится объект, а вам нужно свойство `text()` это объекта:

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  var b = $(this).clone();
  $('ul').append('<li>' + b.text() + '</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Текст 1</span>
<span>Текст 2</span>
<span>Текст 3</span>
<span>Текст 4</span>

<ul></ul>
```